# d3.js - Tooltips only shows the first properties values of the data object

Tags: loops, d3.js, tooltip, each, timeline

First things first, you can play with all the code of the component and the data here: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/timeline-component-tftvg?file=/src/Timeline.tsx)

[image]

I have a `Timeline` component in `d3`, and for each one of the circles I want to show the respective data in the tooltip according to the day of the month. As you can see in the image, I can do it, **the problem here is that in all the tooltips it only shows the first properties value of data`.info`. It doesn't do the "loop" through the tooltips**, like it does for the colors of the circles... and I really think that it's because of the generation of only and exclusive one tooltip per event... i really don't know how to solve this problem as I tried multiple things.

data.tsx:

```
const data = [
  {
    tag: "Vários",
    date: "2021-01-01 00:00:00",
    info: [
      {
        tag: "Prescrição",
        date: "2021-01-01 00:00:00",
        healthProf: "Dr. Ana Martins Noronha"
      },
      {
        tag: "Avaliações",
        date: "2021-01-01 00:00:00",
        healthProf: "Dr. João Palmeira"
      }
    ],
    category: {
      tag: "Vários",
      color: "#999999"
    }
  },
  {
    tag: "Prescrição",
    date: "2021-01-02 00:00:00",
    info: [
      {
        tag: "Diagnõsticos",
        date: "2021-01-02 00:00:00",
        healthProf: "Dr. Roberto Ladeiras"
      }
    ],
    category: {
      tag: "Prescrição",
      color: "#4199e0"
    }
  }, ...
```

I really think the problem comes from the following logic:

Timeline.tsx

```
 tooltip.each(function (d: any, index: number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < d.info.length; i++) {
    tooltip
      .append("span")
      .text((d: any) => {
        return `${d.info[i].tag}: `;
      })
      .attr("width", "1250px")
      .style("color", "#ffffff")
      .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("padding", "0")
      .style("font-size", "10px");

    tooltip
      .append("span")
      .style("font-weight", "regular")
      .text((d: any) => {
        return d.info[i].date;
      })
      .style("color", "#ffffff")
      .style("font-size", "10px");

    tooltip
      .append("div")
      .style("font-weight", "regular")
      .text((d: any) => {
        return d.info[i].healthProf;
      })
      .style("color", "#ffffff")
      .style("font-size", "10px");
  }
});
```

Check the project in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/timeline-component-tftvg?file=/src/Timeline.tsx)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a single instance of the tooltip element (don't call `data`):

```
const tooltip = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .classed("tooltip", true)
  ...
  .style("visibility", "hidden");
```

2. Create `showToolip` and `hideTooltip` function:

```
const showTooltip = d => {
  tooltip.selectAll("*").remove();
  toolip.append("span").text(d.info[0].tag);
  ...
  tooltip
    .attr("left", d => xScale(getDate(d.date)))
    .style("visibility", "visible");
}

const hideTooltip = () => tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
```

3. Create handlers for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
d3.selectAll(".episode")
  .on("mouseenter", d => ShowTooltip(d))
  .on("mouseleave", () => HideTooltip())
```

Comment: Sorry sir, but your answer doesn't work and I can't understand the major difference to get to the solution! Can you try it in the codesandbox link? Thank you very much.

Comment: I see the "episodePositionByDate" but I don't know how to reach that function... And if I don't use the data, how can I load my info? Sorry.

Comment: @PedroRelvas I suppose `left` position should be: `d => xScale(getDate(d.date))`

Comment: it doesn't work at all.... the main problem still the same, it goes straight to the first property of info and doesn't iterate to next ones.... :( thanks